# How can I add slide to existing ppt with PHP without a error for previous slides?

Tags: php, powerpoint, phppresentation

I want to control my .ppt doc with PHP. I can do it with PHPpresentation very well but when I want to add slides to my existing presentation, I can't do it. How can I add slides to my existing presentation without any problems for previous slides? And which script (phppresentation or..) or any solution?

Comment: Check out this library https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation

Comment: I checked it but I can't do it with Phppresentation. How can i do it with it? I can load a existing presentation but when I tried to add new slide to it, previous slides is corrupting.